# Download/Copy zip file from Nexus repository via jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I am new to this. I have a .NET project, GIT is being used as a SCM. We are keeping Third party binaries(in a zip file) inside Nexus.

Now, while building the project, via Jenkins, I need to copy and unzip binaries from Nexus to build machine via Jenkins Pipeline Script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven dependency plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html).
A very basic example would be:

```
sh "mvn dependency:get -DrepoUrl=YOUR_URL Dartifact=com.foo.something:component:LATEST:jar -Ddest=component.jar"
```

Of course this requires java and maven to be properly installed on your node.

Comment: How can I specify usedId and password  for my Nexus repository?

Comment: I do not know whether you can pass username and password over the cli. Normally you set up the file '~/.m2/settings.xml' with a content like:

`<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>YOUR_ID</id>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>`